# Why Aren't My Variables Resetting Every Loop?

Tags: java, object, file-io, initialization

I'm building a gradebook that stores students and teachers, each with a unique ID, and their respective classes enrolled in or teaching in an ArrayList in their Student and Teacher objects. I have the folder path "J:/compsci/Classes/" storing a text file for each class.

Text File Format:

Line 1: Class Name, Teacher ID, Period, Honors?, Class ID

Line 2: Student ID for each student in the class separated by a comma.

Here I am initializing all of the classes each student is taking, all of the classes each teacher is teaching, and all of the students and info for each class.

Based on everything I've learned so far, I'm redefining the class object c inside a local scope for-loop therefore it should be a brand new object with no students initially but in the line below that, it includes the students from all previous classes when printing with the debugging.

Please help I've spent a week trying to fix this

Code with Debugging

```
File[] classes = new File("J:/compsci/Classes/").listFiles();
for (File currentClass: classes) {
    System.out.println(currentClass.getPath());//proves that i'm moving to a different class
    try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (new FileInputStream (currentClass.getPath()))){
        String[] classInfo= fileReader.nextLine().split(",");
        for (String s: classInfo)//all the info going into the parameters for a new class
            System.out.print(s+",");
        System.out.println();
        Class c = new Class (classInfo[0],classInfo[1],Integer.parseInt(classInfo[2]),classInfo[3].equals("H"),currentClassID());
        for (Student s: c.getStudents())//PROBLEM!! should always be empty initially and not store students from previous classes!!
            System.out.print(s.getID()+",");
        System.out.println();
        String[] studentslist= fileReader.nextLine().split(",");
        for (String s: studentslist)
            c.addStudent((Student)getUserFromID(s));
        ((Teacher)getUserFromID(classInfo[1])).addClass(c);
        for (String s: studentslist) {//prints the only students that are actually supposed to be in the class
            System.out.println(s);
            ((Student)getUserFromID(s)).addClass(c);
        }
        CLASSLIST.add(c);//global arraylist storing all classes
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Console Output

```
J:\compsci\Classes\APBiology.txt
AP Biology,00009,5,H,00001,

00001
00003
00004
00011
J:\compsci\Classes\Chinese5AP.txt
Chinese 5 AP,00007,0,H,00002,
00001,00003,00004,00011,
00005
00011
J:\compsci\Classes\ComputerScienceA.txt
Computer Science A,00007,2,H,00003,
00001,00003,00004,00011,00005,00011,
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
J:\compsci\Classes\ComputerSciencePrinciples.txt
Computer Science Principles,00007,3,H,00004,
00001,00003,00004,00011,00005,00011,00001,00002,00003,00004,00005,
00003
00004
00005
00011
00001
```

Code without any Debugging

```
File[] classes = new File("J:/compsci/Classes/").listFiles();
for (File currentClass: classes) {
    try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (new FileInputStream (currentClass.getPath()))){
        String[] classInfo= fileReader.nextLine().split(",");
        String[] studentslist= fileReader.nextLine().split(",");
        Class c = new Class (classInfo[0],classInfo[1],Integer.parseInt(classInfo[2]),classInfo[3].equals("H"),currentClassID());
        ((Teacher)getUserFromID(classInfo[1])).addClass(c);
        for (String s: studentslist)
            c.addStudent((Student)getUserFromID(s));
        for (String s: studentslist)
            ((Student)getUserFromID(s)).addClass(c);
        CLASSLIST.add(c);//global arraylist storing all classes
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: also anyone know how i can put a bounty on this

Comment: you don't have enough reputation I think

Comment: Where's the implementation of Class?

Comment: smells like stundents are static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah ok so apparently i had the arraylist in my class object as static oops. Didn't realize that messed up everything

Answer (score 1):

Since you issue happens just after create new Class c:

```
Class c = new Class (classInfo[0],classInfo[1],Integer.parseInt(classInfo[2]),classInfo[3].equals("H"),currentClassID());
for (Student s: c.getStudents())//PROBLEM!! should always be empty initially and not store students from previous classes!!
```

But you didn't attach your Class constructor, I guess you missed reset List students attriburte. Please add

`students = new ArrayList<>();`

to Class constructor.